# postgresql - How to get one row the min value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table **(t_image)** with this column

```
 datacd   | imagecode | indexdate 
----------------------------------
    A     |    1      |  20170213
    A     |    2      |  20170213
    A     |    3      |  20170214
    B     |    4      |  20170201
    B     |    5      |  20170202
```

desired result is this

```
    datacd   | imagecode | indexdate 
    ----------------------------------
        A    |    1      |  20170213
        B    |    4      |  20170201
```

In the above table, I want to retrieve 1 row for each datacd who has the minimum  index date

Here is my query, but the result returns 2 rows for datacd **A**

```
select *
from (
   select datacd, min(indexdate) as indexdate
   from t_image
   group by datacd
) as t1 inner join t_image as t2 on t2.datacd = t1.datacd and t2.indexdate = t1.indexdate;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Postgres proprietary `distinct on ()` operator is typically the fastest solution for [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) queries:

```
select distinct on (datacd) *
from t_image
order by datacd, indexdate;
```

Comment: this one works.. but performance wise , querying becomes a lil bit slow..

Comment: @john1717: if you have a performance problem, please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then ask a new question, providing the information from the tag description

Answer (score 5):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.datacd,
       t.imagecode,
       t.indexdate
FROM
(
    SELECT datacd, imagecode, indexdate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datacd ORDER BY indexdate) rn
    FROM t_image
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```